# Calculate the determinants of the following matrices

Tags: determinant

so I got this task from my professor and wanted to ask for help
I have this following matrices

(a)

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & -11 & -11 & 45 \\
 1 &  11 & 10 & -83 \\
    1 & -6 & -5 & 81 \\
     0 & -3 & -3 & 42
\end{pmatrix}$$

I did this one with the Laplace expansion stuff $4 \times 4$ and got $42$, though I don't know if it's right yet.

Now here comes the real problem

(b)

$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 1+a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
   a_1 &  1+a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
 \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
    a_1 & a_2 & \dots & 1+a_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

with $a_1, \dots , a_n$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}$.

So how do I do this one ? also with the  Laplace expansion ?
What kind of value should come out ? a something ?
If there were more numbers I could solve it more easily
and I don't know how big it is.. like $4\times 4$ or something.. but it's $n\times n$ so
how am I doing this one

And at last

(c) $$C = (c_{ij})$$ with $c_{ij} = 0$ if $i = j$
$1$ if $i != j$
for $1<i,j<n$

I have the same problem with this one (similiar to b)

It would be nice if someone could give me hints/a solution/etc
Thanks for reading

Comment: There's probably a clever solution to $b$. But I would subtract row 2 from row 1 before attempting cofactor expansion to see a quick path of reduction

Comment: You mean substracting 1+a1, a1, a1.. a1 - a2, 1+a2, a2.. a2 ?

Comment: About $(b)$, look up [Matrix determinant lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). In particular, this is the special case $$\det(I + uv^T) = 1 + v^T u$$ with $u^T = (1,1,\ldots)$ and $v^T = (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

Comment: I don't understand how this can help me after reading the wikipedia article

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\det\begin{bmatrix} 
   1+a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
   a_1 &  1+a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_1 & a_2 & \dots & 1+a_n
\end{bmatrix}
= & \det\left(I_n + \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \otimes 
\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_n\end{bmatrix}
\right)\\
= & 1 + \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_n\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\\
= & 1 + ( a_1 \cdot 1 + a_2 \cdot 1 + \cdots + a_n \cdot 1 )\\
= & 1 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

What I meant for $b$ was:

$$\left|\begin{matrix}1+a & b & c \\ a & 1+b & c \\a & b & 1+c\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ a & 1+b & c \\a & b & 1+c \end{matrix}\right|$$

$$=\left|\begin{matrix}1+b & c  \\ b & 1+c\end{matrix}\right|+\left|\begin{matrix}a & c  \\ a & 1+c\end{matrix}\right|$$

$$=\left|\begin{matrix}1 & -1  \\ b & 1+c\end{matrix}\right|+a\left|\begin{matrix}1 & c  \\ 1 & 1+c\end{matrix}\right|$$

$$=([1+c]+[b])+a([1+c]-[c])=a+b+c+1$$

If you know induction, it will be a very quick proof (if you can see the general solution from the above). Achille Hui's comment gives a much faster route to the solution.

Now for question $c$, it is *almost* a special case of $(b)$. Notice if we choose $a_i=-1$ for all $i$ then the matrix becomes

$$\left(\begin{matrix}0 & -1 & \cdots & -1\\
-1 & 0 & \cdots & -1\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & -1\\ -1 & -1 & \cdots & 0\end{matrix}\right)$$

From the result in $(b)$ the determinant of this matrix is $1-n$. The matrix in $(c)$ is the negative of this one. So factoring out a $(-1)$ from each row will finish it off.

Comment: Thanks for alot for your help but I think I can't choose ai = -1  it can only be 0 or 1.. according to my understanding.. besides that i, j lie between 1 and n anyway.. so it's not possible for it to be -1 in my opinion unless I have a thinking error..

Comment: While when I looked at the B of Achilles I kinda got the idea but didn't understand it fully yet.. so I will try to think of an own idea I can understand better.. with your ideas as support

Comment: Take a minute and digest what I wrote. I did not specifically refer to the given matrix. But the matrix in the question is the negative of the one I gave

Comment: And in your solution I can see that you used the Laplace expansion I guess but I don't understand the values 1 - 1 and 0 yet..how you got them I mean.. or I'm just too tired atm to do math since I've been ill for a while

Comment: Adding a multiple of one row to another does not affect the determinant.

Comment: Alright I kinda did the (c) before the b

Comment: All main diagonals are 0 there.. the rest is 1.. I think the determinant is 0 because it's a skew symmetric matrix.. are my thoughts right ?

Comment: No, the determinant is $(-1)^n(1-n)$ as I tried to explain

Comment: Ok I proved the (c) of the other task.. now I tried to comprehend what you did here.. but aren't you missing by the cofactor expansion the case: a 1+b, a +b ? and how do you get the a in front of the other one ? I thought of a * 1 = a1 and a 1 first for the first row but what about the c then.. can you explain me that ?

Comment: I think your past teachers have done you a disservice on how to find determinants. This is a topic for an entire lecture at a university. You can factor constants out of rows or columns by multiplying the determinant by that constant. See page 4 of this noteset: http://www.math.pitt.edu/~annav/0290H/row_reduction.pdf